# XCode 8 Git pull does not load into XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have a problem pulling from remote with XCode 8. Problem is when I do Git pull, it pulls all changes, and I see that new classes are added in Finder window but it does NOT load them into XCode project. I need to add them manually in XCode every time to my project. I've tried from terminal, source tree and inside XCode, every time, same thing. With prior XCodes everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also getting change in xcodeproj file? May be the latest commit to server missed pushing changes to xcodeproj because of which Xcode is not able to figure out new classes etc. Xcodeproj file is the way via which Xcode recognise changes to project structure.

Comment: Yes, I am getting changes in project.pbxproj

Comment: I believe there is a bug in source control of New Xcode. It doesn't merge the code from remote